# What if you make a PUT request and there is no such entity on server?

Tags: rest, http, web, put

What happenes if you try to update an entity on server (make a `PUT` request), but there is no such entity?

Will server create an entity or respond with an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the HTTP/1.1 Spec server **can create a new entity**:

> The **PUT** method requests that the enclosed entity be stored under the supplied Request-URI.
>
> If the Request-URI refers to an already existing resource, the enclosed entity SHOULD be considered as a modified version of the one residing on the origin server.
>
> **If the Request-URI does not point to an existing resource, and that URI is capable of being defined as a new resource** by the requesting user agent,
>   the origin **server can create the resource** with that URI.
>
> **If** a new resource is **created**, the origin **server MUST inform** the user agent **via** the 201 (Created) **response**.